# How to define text spacing in input in css

Tags: css

How to define text spacing in input in css. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Row spacing:

```
input {
   line-height: 10pt;
}
```

Answer (score 13):

what does "text spacing" mean? letter-spacing or word-spacing? for this, you could do:

```
input{
letter-spacing: 8px;
word-spacing: 16px;
}
```

or do you want to have some space between the text and the border of the input? in this case, you should use `padding:...`

Answer (score 5):

CSS:

```
input{ letter-spacing: 0.1em}
```